# Link on SSRS Report to Export / Render to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to add a link to an SSRS R2 Report that should open the report in Excel.

Many sites suggest to add a text box with a link that uses the following expression

```
=Globals!ReportServerUrl &  Globals!ReportFolder & "/" & Globals!ReportName & "&rs:Format=excel"
```

So I did. SSRS works. The Report rendered in SSRS/IE works. But if I click the text box to open it in Excel, it does not work. The expression is 'calculated' correctly and returns the correct path, but IE returns an error "HTTP 400 bad Request" "The webpage cannot be found"

Any suggestions why this happens? I double checked server names and paths as well as manually tried a variety of URL combinations, but it never exports to excel. The "standard" drop-down save as excel does work tough.

Thanks!

Comment: Use fiddler to capture the http request when you click export to excel.  That should give you the correct URL you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to try.

Use fiddler to capture the http request when you click export to excel.

That should give you the correct URL you are looking for.  Once you have that, just drop it into your browser of choice and see if it works.

Next put the URL into an SSRS report as a link and try again.  once that is working go for the calculated option.